# MySQL Query JOIN 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Looking to join 3 tables, but having trouble on the last one.

`members`

```
ID | name
---------
1  | John
2  | Jane
3  | Jack
```

`member_points` (can have multiple transactions between members)

```
ID | date | id_from | id_to
---------------------------
1  | 8/8  |    1    |   2
2  | 8/8  |    1    |   2
3  | 8/8  |    3    |   2
```

`member_ratings` (one member can only rate another member, one time)

```
ID | id_from | id_to | rating
-----------------------------
1  |    2    |   1   |   5
```

Each member may rate each member only once, and can only rate the member they received a point from, based on the `member_points` table.

My current query achieves this, however I'm having difficulty introducing the 3rd table, that will include the rating accoringly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$sql = '
SELECT *, 
    m.id AS id, 
    c1.id AS id_from, 
    c1.name AS name_from,
    c2.id AS id_to, 
    c2.name AS name_to
FROM member_points AS m
JOIN members AS c1 ON m.id_from = c1.id
JOIN members AS c2 ON m.id_to = c2.id
    and m.id_to='.$_SESSION["userid"].'
GROUP BY name_from';
```

My goal is join the 3rd table so I can call the associated rating.

```
ID | name_from | name_to | rating
----------------------------------
1  |     2     |    1    |   5     
2  |     2     |    3    | pending
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: `COALESCE(t3.rating, 'pending')`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrew you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to join in the `member_ratings` table like this:

```
$sql = '
SELECT *, 
    m.id AS id, 
    c1.id AS id_from, 
    c1.name AS name_from,
    c2.id AS id_to, 
    c2.name AS name_to,
    IF(mr.rating IS NULL, 'pending', mr.rating) AS rating 
FROM member_points AS m
JOIN members AS c1 ON m.id_from = c1.id
JOIN members AS c2 ON m.id_to = c2.id
    and m.id_to='.$_SESSION["userid"].'
LEFT JOIN member_ratings AS mr ON mr.id_from = c1.id
    AND mr.id_to = c2.id
GROUP BY name_from';
```

please let me know if this isn't what you need and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: @Andrew the original answer I posted was referencing the `members` table wrong, I fixed it now

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for... thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Andrew There is no problem in MySQL for which the above is an appropriate or valid solution.

Comment: @Strawberry Here is an example of how this solution works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df54c7/1 The data that the OP indicated to be in the tables is a little off between what he said is in the tables and what he wants to be displayed, but the solution is valid. It left joins in the `member_ratings` table in so that the value in the `rating` column from that table will be included in the result set. That is what the OP was asking about, how to get the `rating` value from `member_ratings` into the query that he had written.

Comment: No. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. And never use `SELECT *`. Anyway, next time good bring to you.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree that it doesn't need to be there, but the query still works to do what the OP asked for. All he needs to do is to leave off the `GROUP BY`, but having the `GROUP BY` in there doesn't change the fact that the query still works. I just wanted to point out that the problem the OP asked about is solved by the answer I provided. As well as the`SELECT *`, it's not best practices, but simply removing it like I did in the sql fiddle example shows that the query is still valid.

Comment: If you leave off the GROUP BY clause then I concede that you then have a valid query. However, I suspect that the OP would like a DISTINCT set of results, which would be meaningless in the context of `SELECT *`

Comment: Also, this query remains open to sql injection

Comment: @Strawberry I agree, but the main issue the OP was asking about was how to bring in the `rating` value from the `member_ratings` table into the query that he had developed thus far, which is what I showed him how to do. Again, I just wanted to clarify that your statement "There is no example in MySQL for which the above is an appropriate or valid solution" is not true. He was asking about how to bring in the `rating` value, and my solution does that. Now, if he was asking about how to guard against SQL Injection or how to get a distinct list, that would be a different question.

Comment: My statement is true. Your query returns an indeterminate result, and would fail in every other RDBMS - and more modern versions of MySQL (without tweaking default settings)